# Delete last word between two characters VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way that I can delete the last "word" in  a textbox? Each word or string would be separated by a  comma (",")

This is what I have at the minute, but I am open to new suggestions

```
        Dim deleteItem() As String = Split(TextBox2.Text, ", ")
        Array.Resize(deleteItem, deleteItem.Length - 1)
        For i = 0 To UBound(deleteItem)
            TextBox2.Text = deleteItem(i)
        Next
```

Any help would be great thanks :)

Comment: `TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0,TextBox2.Text.LastIndexOf(",")).Trim()`

Comment: @Codexer Ill give that answer a try, is there anything I need to delete in my code above ??

Comment: @Codexer that got it working, thanks so much.

Comment: If it worked why don't you mark the answer or vote? It helps others that come across same problem and or issue.

Comment: @Codexer how do I give you rep or whatever system this site uses ??

Comment: Check the checkmark by my name and or click the up arrow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [**LastIndexOf Function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0,TextBox2.Text.LastIndexOf(",")).Trim()
```

Comment: I may be pushing my luck, but is there any way to keep the last comma ?? instead of it leaving the string like this.....  
     hello  ....
Can it be left like this.... 
      hello,   ....

Comment: There's other ways, but just add it back `TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0,TextBox2.Text.LastIndexOf(",")).Trim() & ","`

Comment: @Codexer, why not like this : TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0,TextBox2.Text.LastIndexOf(",") + 1).Trim()

Comment: ugh, im so stupid. Didn't think of that, but thanks a lot

Comment: @Benoit that work's as well, there's more than one way :)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just get the substring till the last `,`

```
TextBox2.Text = TextBox2.Text.Substring(0,TextBox2.Text.LastIndexOf(","))
```